# Should child method signatures support all arguments that its parent method accepts?

Tags: oop

Here is some Ruby syntax, but the question applies to object-oriented design in general.

Suppose I have a Window class (window as in, a GUI window). You can construct a window by initializing the position and its size.

```
class Window
  def initialize(x, y, width, height)
  end
end
```

And suppose I have a specific type of window that inherits from the base `Window`.

```
class Scrolling_Window < Window
  def initialize(x, y)
     super(x, y, 200, 50)
  end
end
```

Notice here that *my intention* was to draw the window with a fixed size, but you are free to choose where the window should be placed. It comes with cool scrolling functionality and other things that a "regular window" shouldn't have because they're not, by design, meant to be scrolling windows.

Now what if someone wants to inherit from the `Scrolling_Window` because they want to create a type of scrolling window, with some extra features of its own, but would like a less "restricted" signature

```
class Another_Window < Child_Window

  def initialize(x, y, width, height)
    super(x, y)
    # oops, now the width and height are pretty much stuck
  end
end
```

As you can see, if someone decided they wanted to use cool methods defined in `Scrolling_Window`, they are stuck with having to either duplicate the methods and give up on inheriting from my `Scrolling_Window`, or find something else to do.

## Question

Is it generally better to transparently pass all variables from children to their parents? Does "good OOP" design specify anything about method signatures?

(The example is questionable design but I can't think of a better example.)

Comment: If `Scrolling_Window` is intended to be used as a base class then obviously any arrangement that prevents derived classes from changing its dimensions is bad design. But surely the members backing `width` and `height` would be `protected` in any case? Esp. in Ruby it's AFAIK impossible to let a window resize itself but prevent derived windows from doing so.

Comment: @Jon: Is that so? Isn't it rather that *if* `Scrolling_Window` is intended to be used as a base class, then it must prevent derived classes from changing dimensions if and only if there is a reason why any `Scrolling_Window` (i.e. instances of that type and of subtypes) has fixed dimensions. cf. a statement like "all widgets are freely adjustable in width and height, but text boxes, a special kind of widget, have a height of exactly one line of text (which includes basic text boxes and all special subtypes of text boxes)"

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Purely theoretically, yes. But if that were the case then `Scrolling_Window` would be a really bad choice of class name because we established that this type of window has some attribute that requires it have a fixed size. That attribute should be reflected in its class name. Also, IMHO building "generalized" scrolling functionality into a specific-use-case class like that would be further indication of bad design. But we are well into speculation territory here.

Comment: @Jon: Always consider identifiers in the context of their namespace (which we don't know here). Though otherwise I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

`Derived class objects must be substitutable for the base class objects. That means objects of the derived class must behave in a manner consistent with the promises made in the base class' contract.`

LSP is about interfaces and contracts as well as how to decided when to extend a class vs. use another strategy such as composition to achieve your goal.

In your case you are concerned about method signatures, I would say that as long as your class still meets any previous contracts and behavioural expectations, then extend, overload or change as you please.

Simply keep in mind the above and you will come to the correct conclusion.